# JqGrid issue on formatter

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using this jqgrid:

```
$("#griglia-navgrid").jqGrid( { 
        colNames:[...],               
        colModel:[ {name:'ZMENG_SOR_VRKME_PREC', index:'ZMENG_SOR_VRKME_PREC', width:'5', sortable:false, formatter:numFormat},  ],
        ...
       footerrow:true,
       afterInsertRow: function(id){    $("#griglia-navgrid").jqGrid('setCell',id,'ZPARVW_Z1','',{'text-decoration':'underline'}); },
               loadComplete: function () {
               var $this = $(this),
                sum = $this.jqGrid("getCol", "ZMENG_SOR_VRKME", false, "sum"),
                $footerRow = $(this.grid.sDiv).find("tr.footrow"),localData = $this.jqGrid("getGridParam", "data"),totalRows = localData.length,totalSum = 0,   $newFooterRow, i;
 $newFooterRow = $(this.grid.sDiv).find("tr.myfootrow");
            if ($newFooterRow.length === 0) {
                $newFooterRow = $footerRow.clone();
                $newFooterRow.removeClass("footrow").addClass("myfootrow ui-widget-content");
                $newFooterRow.children("td").each(function () {
                    this.style.width = ""; // remove width from inline CSS
                });
                $newFooterRow.insertAfter($footerRow);
            }
            for (i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) {
                if(localData[i].ZMENG_SOR_VRKME.search("-") == -1){
                     totalSum += parseFloat(localData[i].ZMENG_SOR_VRKME);}
                else{
                    totalSum -= parseFloat(localData[i].ZMENG_SOR_VRKME);
                    }
            }
            $newFooterRow.find(">td[aria-describedby=" + this.id + "_ZPARVW_Z1_NAME]").text("Totale:");
            $newFooterRow.find(">td[aria-describedby=" + this.id + "_ZMENG_SOR_VRKME]").text(
                $.fmatter.util.NumberFormat(totalSum, $.jgrid.formatter.number.decimalSeparator=',')
            );
        }
    }); //jqGrid

    function numFormat( cellvalue, options, rowObject ){
        return cellvalue.replace(".",",");
    }
```

It'w works on Safari and Chrome. In firefox i have an error: "ReferenceError: numFormat is not defined".

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: can you show the rest of your code? where is $("#grid").jqGrid() called, is it inside a function itself?

Comment: `"ReferenceError: <> is not defined"` is general error found when it doesn't found expected object reference. Please try defining function "numFormat" before the jqgrid definition.

If that doesn't work please update whole code for jQGrid in question, there may be miss in that too.

Comment: Tks Pranav, i put  function "numFormat" before of JQGrid.. Tks a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

The formatter functions should be placed before the JQGrid definition.
THen it would work.